# How can I crawl all reviews of an app on Google Play Store?

Tags: android, google-play, web-crawler

When I crawl an app page on Google Play Store, I could only crawl the first few pages of an app review.

(The next page of app review is showed up when I click the arrow button using the web browser)

How can I crawl the others of reviews?

Comment: This is a good question. It's possible for individual devs to export their own reviews and ratings but it would be great if anyone could export all reviews. My suspicion is that Google won't allow this because it would reveal that some phones generate more negative reviews, and then everyone would realize that it must be the phone manufacturer's fault and not the dev's if some phones are generating a disproportionate number of 1-star "crashed" ratings because of their bad drivers etc.

Comment: Have you tried to figure out what pressing the arrow does? It's probably an ajax query of some sort you could take advantage of.

Comment: @Huey No, I didn't. Frankly speaking, I don't know how to do it. Could you tell me how can I figure out that?

Comment: Please check my answer in this link [http://stackoverflow.com/a/35249793/5435658](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35249793/5435658) Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I checked out [Telegram](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.telegram.messenger)'s Google Play page and it seems all the reviews are loaded together with the rest of the page.

Reviews visible without clicking arrow
[image: initially]

After clicking the arrow, the reviews section increases in size and shows full-length reviews
[image: full-length]

Then, you can look and older and "less helpful" reviews by clicking the right arrow.
[image: older]

However, all these reviews have been loaded from the start:

[image]
[image]

From there, you'd have to parse the HTML using your web crawler to get the reviews.

**EDIT**

Okay, after clicking the arrow a few times, Google Play starts to load some older reviews by pinging `http://play.google.com/store/getreviews` with a token of sorts.

[image: web dev]

This is a snippet of the response I got:

[image: response]

```
<div class="single-review">  <a href="/store/people/details?id=113340797493751556969">...
```

It seems to contain all the loaded reviews, so all you'll have to do is to parse that, or try to figure out how the token works so you can fetch from `getreviews` yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, If you click the arrow button several times until loading mark is shown up upon the button, you'll see that the reviews which are shown up after the loading mark are not loaded on the HTML from the start.

Comment: Got it, thanks! Now, I can crawl all reviews of apps!!

Comment: ycyoon could you please tell me how to do it?

Comment: @ycyoon if your project is opensource, can you share your code for crawling all reviews of an app?

Comment: Does anyone know how to get token? or how does this token generate?

Comment: @ycyoon how you do that?

Comment: Found how he did it. The token is always the same. Look at the form Data from his screenshot. It has a value pageNum. So basicly you can test this in Postman. Sent the same form-data as in the screenshot and iterate trough the pageNum

Answer (score 0):

It's too late though but you can use BeautifulSoup library for python to crawl all the reviews. All reviews are inside div having class 'single-review'.

Create a soup object of the html of the webpage, select all the instances of 'single-review' class.

> soup.select('.single-review')

will do it for you. Extract whatever you want from a review. For reference you might want to checkout the BeautifulSoup [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

You don't need to check for right arrow or left arrow. Above method will give you all the review currently on the webpage.